# Normalization of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, normalization

I need to normalize a plot to a grayscale from 0 to 255. The data is in .txt format. This is the rough plotting that I have:

```
clf;
%call importdata() after changing current directory
B = importdata('sigpros.txt');

d  = 1000; %vertical spacing
Bs = B;    %copy of the original data

for i = 1 : size(Bs,2)
    %loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) + (i-1) * d;
end    

%plot the modified matrix
plot(Bs);
```

The data consist of 349 rows and 4007 columns. Each column is a full A-scan data (a wave form). Each data has a vertical spacing and a full set of these plotted data makes a B-scan data (Waveform attained from displacement of a sensor). I am not sure if the code above is correct but the data should look something like: [B-Scan data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toq3I.png).

This can be attained with normalization of the matrix plot above to a grayscale 0 to 255. Currently, this is how my plot looks like: [My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdKv4.jpg). Please help me get the desired B-scan plot like above! Thanks!

**UPDATES**

This is the [normalized b-scan data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EmkS.jpg). However, the way it initially peaks is higher than the one in the above image. What could be the problem here?

**Zero offset removal**

```
clf;
%call importdata() after changing current directory
B = importdata('A_scan1.txt');
Bd = detrend(B,0); %remove the zero offset

d  = 1000; %vertical spacing
Bs = Bd;    %copy of the original data

for i = 1 : size(Bs,2)
    %loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) + (i-1) * d;
end    

minV = min(Bs(:));
maxV = max(Bs(:));
Bs_scale = (Bs-minV)*255/(maxV-minV);

%plot the modified matrix
plot(Bs_scale, 'k');
```

However, it still doesn't start from 0.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking for.  Looking at the 2 plots the only difference (besides more lines) is that yours is in color.  Do you just want to turn all the lines black or gray?  if so just do this `plot(Bs,'k');`

Comment: I need to also normalize the plot to 0 to 255.. That is what I was told. Is there any way I could normalize a matrix plot?

Comment: I am not sure of exactly how you want it normalized.  You could rescale everything so that the Max of  `Bs` becomes 255 & then min of `Bs` becomes 0.  Note: currently you have some negative values in both of your example plots so an offset would be applied.

Comment: Something like this:  `minV = min(Bs(:));`  `maxV = max(Bs(:));`  `Bs_scale = (Bs-minV)*255/(maxV-minV);`   then `plot(Bs_scale,'k');` ... If that is what you are after I can put it in an answer ... but seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: Why is it arbitrary? I could try what you did and I will inform you.

Comment: I don't know the details of what this information represents.  Shifting up to remove negatives & rescaling might be losing important information ... maybe.  You would know better than I if this messes up your data somehow.

Comment: @AeroEngy thanks! I think we're one step closer thanks to you. however, as you can see from the B-scan data, the normalized plot peaks higher than the B-scan data above. How could this be solved?

Comment: @AeroEngy and do you know what I should do to remove the zero offset? as you can see the b-scan data starts at 0 but the normalized starts at 75

Comment: Ill write something as an answer soon...im away from pc now

Comment: See the answer below.  If it helps upvote/accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set on offset so the starting point of the first line is at zero and scale all the data so that the Range from min to max value is 255 units.

I commented out but included some lines that would alternative scale the data so that it starts at 0 & the peak is at 255.  However, since you have some negative values then the total range is > 255.

```
clf;
%call importdata() after changing current directory
B = importdata('sigpros.txt');

%NOTE: I am only plotting the first 59 lines as the rest don't look as good
Bd = detrend(B(:,1:59),0); %remove the zero offset

d  = 1000; %vertical spacing
Bs = Bd;    %copy of the original data

%Get the initial zero offset from the first line
initOffset = Bs(1,1);
%% xxx Alternatively take the mean across all starting points xxx
% initOffset = mean(Bs(1,:));

for i = 1 : size(Bs,2)
    %loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) - initOffset + (i-1) * d ; %subtract the offset from each
end    

minV = min(Bs(:));
maxV = max(Bs(:));

%This make the RANGE from min to make = 0-255 units.
Bs_scale = (Bs)*255/(maxV-minV);
%% xxxx If instead you want the peak to be at 255 xxxxx
% Bs_scale = (Bs)*255/(maxV);

%plot the modified matrix
plot(Bs_scale, 'k');
```

**EDIT/Explanation:**

[Here is what B looks like Raw.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij7Bz.png).  It is basically a series of lines all on top of each other.  After you `detrend` it removes most of the constant offset. 
 However, since this signal isn't perfectly symmetrical these lines do not start exactly at zero ... they are closer than they were but are not perfect.  [Here is Bd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peWdx.png) after `detrend`  Note that each line does not start at exactly zero.

Next your `for` loop originally spaced each line apart by 1000 by added a multiple of `d` [so it looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Wmj.png).  Since theses lines do not start exactly at zero which is what you asked for I added the initial offset term.  These basically takes the first point of the first line and subtracts that from every line also.  Thus forcing it to begin at exactly zero.

Comment: could you elaborate how initOffset = Bs(1,1); fixed the zero offset? Thanks

Comment: See Edit for an explanation